# Issue with libxml2 when using ruby 1.9.3 from rvm on Mac OS X 10.7.4

Tags: ruby, installation, rubygems, libxml2

I'm trying to install [kitabu](https://github.com/jstorimer/kitabu) with gem on Mac OS X 10.7.4. With pre-installed ruby of version 1.8.X, I got an error saying that I should use 1.9 or later version of ruby.

I installed rvm and tried to use gem from rvm `sudo gem install kitabu` to get this error.

```
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... no
-----
libxml2 is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html     for help with installing dependencies.
```

Using `port install libxml2`, I installed libxml2, but rvm doesn't seem to link against this library.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you need to have libxml2 headers in your system (it is required to build native extensions for this gem)

with macports its `sudo port install libxml2` with brewd should work with `brew install libxml2`

more reading here in portfile http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=library&substr=libxml2 if you have linux http://www.techsww.com/tutorials/libraries/libxml/installation/installing_libxml_on_ubuntu_linux.php and if you have windows i don't have a clue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but it seems that some of the libraries of native OS X and port kind of mingled, when I removed the /opt/local/lib from `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/opt/local/lib`, it seems tot work.